# Sorting aggregation addToSet result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to get result of $addToSet as sorted array ?

I tried to expand the pipeline and $unwind the array, sort it and group it again ,
but still the result isn't sorted.

The arrays are pretty big and i try to avoid sort them in the the application.

```
Document Example :

    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("52a84825cc8391ab188b4567"),
      "id" : 129624
      "message" : "Sample",
      "date" : "12-09-2013,17:34:34",
      "dt" : ISODate("2013-12-09T17:34:34.000Z"),

    }
```

Query :

```
    db.uEvents.aggregate(
    [
      {$match : {dt : {$gte : new Date(2014,01,01) , $lt : new Date(2015,01,17)}}}
      ,{$sort : {dt : 1}}
      , {$group : {
        _id : {
                id : "$id"
                , year : {'$year' : "$dt"}
                , month : {'$month' : "$dt"}
                , day : {'$dayOfMonth' : "$dt"}
            }
        ,dt : {$addToSet : "$dt"}

      }}    
    ]

    );
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but approach it differently. I'm just provide my own data for this, but you'll get the concept.

My Sample:

```
{ "array" : [  2,  4,  3,  5,  2,  6,  8,  1,  2,  1,  3,  5,  9,  5 ] }
```

I'm going to "semi-quote" the CTO on this and state that **Sets** are considered to be **unordered**.

> There is an actual JIRA, Google groups statement that goes something like that. So let's take it from "Elliot" and accept that this **will** be the case.

So if you want an ordered result, you have to massage that way with stages like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Initial unwind
    {"$unwind": "$array"},

    // Do your $addToSet part
    {"$group": {"_id": null, "array": {"$addToSet": "$array" }}},

    // Unwind it again
    {"$unwind": "$array"},

    // Sort how you want to
    {"$sort": { "array": 1} },

    // Use $push for a regular array
    {"$group": { "_id": null, "array": {"$push": "$array" }}}

])
```

And then do whatever. But now your array is sorted.

Comment: This is Correct! but its strange that when on last stage i use $addToSet and not $push its not ordered.

Comment: @alon_r It's not strange at all. And **specifically** because of what I quoted from the CTO of MongoDB. "Set's are considered to be unordered". FYI, "Elliot" has also made comments that **sets** may end up being considered their **own** data type, separate from arrays. Hence the need to *re-cast* the distinction. Up-vote when you get some rep. That's a lot of knowledge for free.

Answer (score 2):

Since mongoDB version 5.2 you can do it without `$unwind`:

The `$setIntersection` create a set out of the array and the `$sortArray` sorts it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {array: {$setIntersection: ["$array"]}}},
  {$set: {$sortArray: {input: "$array", sortBy: 1}}}
])
```