# How to sort the $addToSet within a $group?

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

** **UPDATED** **

Hello MongoDB-Experts,

I am a trainee as a software-developer and I haven't much experience with the MongoDB.

I want to sort certain values in an $addToSet field. I basically want to sort the "firmen" (companies) in the $group. How can I do this?

Many thanks for your help in advance.
t.koelpin

Here is my PHP-Code which I used:

```
$sumQuery = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            'startzeit' => array(
                '$gte' => new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-01-01 01:00:00")),
                '$lte' => new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-01-01 08:00:00"))
            )
        )    
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                'portal' => '$portal',
                'protokoll' => '$protokoll'
            ),
            'daten' => array(
                '$addToSet' => array(
                    'firmen' => '$firma'
                )
            ),
            'count' => array(
                '$sum' => 1
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            '_id' => 1          
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            '_id' => 0,
            'portal' => '$_id.portal',
            'protokoll' => '$_id.protokoll',
            'firmen' => '$daten.firmen',
            'connections' => '$count'
        )
    )
);
```

Here is my unsorted PHP-output:

[image: unsorted PHP-output]

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll copy and paste the code right here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting aggregation addToSet result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967233/sorting-aggregation-addtoset-result)

Comment: No, it's definetely not the same!

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question. Can you explain how is it different than the aforementioned question?

Comment: As you can see from the attached image I've ordered the $group by "portals" then ordered to "protocols". Now I want to order the "companies" without changing the previous order. Do you understand me so far?

Comment: I can see that but as I said it's similar to the other question. `Unwinding` and `grouping` again will not change the previous order. The only difference will be to preserve the `connections count`. I will post my answer, please verify if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in @Neil [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21967302/2745704) as well as in this [Jira Ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8512) `sets` will be unordered.

Extending on Neil answer this can be achieved using the following steps:

1. `Unwind` the set.
2. `Sort` based on the field.
3. `Group` field with `$push`.

As `unwinding` and `grouping` will not change the order of result, the only challenge is to preserve the value of `Connections`. That can be achieved using `$first` or `$max` operator.

Here is the modified PHP Code to achieve this.

```
    $sumQuery = array(
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                'startzeit' => array(
                    '$gte' => new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-01-01 01:00:00")),
                    '$lte' => new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-01-01 08:00:00"))
                )
            )    
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array(
                    'portal' => '$portal',
                    'protokoll' => '$protokoll'
                ),
                'daten' => array(
                    '$addToSet' => array(
                        'firmen' => '$firma'
                    )
                ),
                'count' => array(
                    '$sum' => 1
                )
            )
        ),

        //Unwinding daten.firmen
        array('$unwind' =>  '$daten.firmen'),

        //Sorting the values
        array(
            '$sort' => array(
                'daten.firmen' => 1          
            )
        ),

        //$push creates an array so the sorted order is preserved
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array(
                    'portal' => '$_id.portal',
                    'protokoll' => '$_id.protokoll'
                ),
                'daten' => array(
                    '$push' => array(
                        'firmen' => '$daten.firmen'
                    )
                ),
                'count' => array(
                    '$max' => '$count'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$sort' => array(
                '_id' => 1          
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                '_id' => 0,
                'portal' => '$_id.portal',
                'protokoll' => '$_id.protokoll',
                'firmen' => '$daten.firmen',
                'connections' => '$count'
            )
        )
    );
```

PS: I am not sure about the syntax for PHP. Please verify and fix any minor errors.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try this tomorrow and will send you a feedback

Comment: This works best for me and meets my expectations. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to be of help. But Blakes Seven's answer is more efficient as it eliminates the overhead of `$unwind` and re-grouping.

Answer (score 1):

The true case is that of course a "set" is not considered to be ordered in any way, so if you expect the elements to be ordered then you need to treat them in such a way that is not a "set".

Better than "unwinding" the array produced by [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is essentially to just [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on the values to be contained in the array first, as part of the grouping key. Anything in the grouping key is by definition a "distinct" value, so if you `$group` there first then you can again `$group` later to "roll up" the array after processing the elements with `$sort`.

This is going to save a lot of overhead on first rolling up the array with `$addToSet` and then "de-normalizing" again just in order to sort the content, as this can be quite expensive:

```
$sumQuery = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            'startzeit' => array(
                '$gte' => new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-01-01 01:00:00")),
                '$lte' => new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-01-01 08:00:00"))
            )
        )    
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                'portal' => '$portal',
                'protokoll' => '$protokoll',
                'daten' => '$firmen'
            ),
            'count' => array(
                '$sum' => 1
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            '_id' => 1
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                'portal' => '$_id.portal',
                'protokoll' => '$_id.protokoll'
            ),
            'daten' => array( '$push' => '$_id.daten'),
            'count' => array(
                '$sum' => '$count'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            '_id' => 0,
            'portal' => '$_id.portal',
            'protokoll' => '$_id.protokoll',
            'firmen' => '$daten',
            'connections' => '$count'
        )
    )
);
```

Noting also that if you expect a certain "field order" from a `$project` stage, then none of the field names can be present in an earlier stage, otherwise MongoDB simply "copies" that output into an earlier document position as an optimisation.

It is generally advised to **not** use such a `$project` stage at the end of your pipeline and just accept the results as returned. Doing so adds an additional pass to the returned results in order to do the field renaming. So if no calculations are required here, you are just spending memory and CPU cycles clearly for the sake of re-orginizing field naming.

That is generally better handled in the client code recieving the result than by forcing the aggregation pipeline to do it. But if you `$group` in two stages, being first at the wider level and with a `$sort` in between, then that is your best way to return a "distinct" list without incurring the performance penalty of `$unwind` and then re-grouping the results again.