# $Sort $addToSet within $group's - MongoDB queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Currently I have:

```
db.questionanswers.aggregate( 
  [ 
    sessionStarted: {$first: "$created"}, QuestionsSubmitted: {$last: "$created"}, answer: {$addToSet: "$answer"}}}
  ],
  {
    allowDiskUse: true
  }
)
```

Which aggregates a list of objects with answers group in each one related by quizID and sessionID.

After looking at this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967233/sorting-aggregation-addtoset-result#answer-21967302) to sort my $addToSet array, I amend my query to:

```
db.questionanswers.aggregate( 
  [ 
    {$unwind: "$answer"},
    {$group : {_id : {sessionId: "$sessionId", quizID: "$quizId" }, answer: {$addToSet: "$answer"} }},
    {$unwind : "$answer"},
    {$sort : {"answer": 1}},
    {$group : { _id : {sessionId: "$sessionId", quizID: "$quizId" }, sessionStarted: {$first: "$created"}, QuestionsSubmitted: {$last: "$created"}, answer: {$push: "$answer"}}}
  ],
  {
    allowDiskUse: true
  }
)
```

I get in Robomongo `script executed successfully, but there are no results to show`.

I 've tried toggling `_id : null` from the [same answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967233/sorting-aggregation-addtoset-result#answer-21967302) and my `_id : {sessionId: "$sessionId", quizID: "$quizId" }` query but it doesn't return any results, except when using `_id : null` on both and returns all the sorted answers in one giant group, which makes sense but it's not what I'm after. Any ideas how I can sort each answer `$addToSet` using `$group`?

EDIT:

Aggregating from

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
  "quizId" : "xxx",
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "questionId" : "gender",
  "categoryId" : "1",
  "question" : "male or female",
  "answer" : "male",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-12-xxx"),
  "__v" : 0
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
  "quizId" : "xxx",
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "questionId" : "gender",
  "categoryId" : "1",
  "question" : "question 1",
  "answer" : "answer a",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-12-xxx"),
  "__v" : 0
}, // etc //
```

EDIT2:

Expected output:

```
{
  "_id" : {
    "quizId" : "xxx",
    "sessionId" : "xxx",
  },
  "sessionStarted" : "2015-12-xxx",
  "QuestionsSubmitted" : "2015-12-xxx"
  "answer" : {
    "0" : "answer a",
    "1" : "answer b"
    // etc //
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the sample document ?

Answer (score -1):

There are two problem

1)

```
 sessionStarted: {$first: "$created"}
```

as aggregation has pipeline stages,
there is no `created` variable in your first `$group` pipeline stage so ,add created variable first

2)

Your second group stage is

```
{$group : { _id : {sessionId: "$sessionId", quizID: "$quizId" }, sessionStarted: {$first: "$created"}, QuestionsSubmitted: {$last: "$created"}, answer: {$push: "$answer"}}}
```

Here there is no sessionId variable,
replace

```
$sessionId with $_id.sessionId
```

and

```
$quizIdwith $_id.quizId
```

Here is your answer,please try this one

```
db.questionanswers.aggregate( 
  [ 
    {$group : {_id : {sessionId: "$sessionId", quizID: "$quizId" }, answer: {$addToSet: "$answer"},sessionStarted: {$first: "$created"}, QuestionsSubmitted: {$last: "$created"} },
    {$unwind : "$answer"},
    {$sort : {answer: 1}},
    {$group : { _id : {sessionId: "$_id.sessionId", quizID: "$_id.quizId" }, sessionStarted: {$first: "$sessionStarted"}, QuestionsSubmitted: {$last: "$QuestionsSubmitted"}, answer: {$addToSet: "$answer"}}}
  ]
)
```

Please try this ones

Comment: Added output I'm after. Thank you

Comment: None of the above worked, still returns `executed successfully, but there are no results to show`. Also tried combinations of _id.answer.