# How can i sort addtoset grouped results mongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Currently I have the following:

```
db.questionanswers.aggregate(
  [
    {
        $group : { _id : {sessionId: "$sessionId", quizId: "$quizId" },
            sessionId: {$first: "$sessionId"},
            quizId: { $first: "$quizId"},
            sessionStarted: {$first: "$created"},
            QuestionSubmitted: {$last: "$created"},
            answer: {$addToSet: "$answer"} }     
    }, 
  ] 
)
```

After trying many combinations of $sort, $each, $push, $unwind, $orderby, I'm unable, at this point, to sort the `answer` field, with the answers still being still in the `$group`s defined.

Aggregating from :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
  "quizId" : "xxx",
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "questionId" : "q1",
  "answer" : "answer a",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-12-xxx"),
  "__v" : 0
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
  "quizId" : "xxx",
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "questionId" : "q2",
  "answer" : "answer b",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-12-xxx"),
  "__v" : 0
}, // etc //
```

Using mongoDB's `$out` to output:

```
{
  "_id" : {
    "quizId" : "xxx",
    "sessionId" : "xxx",
  },
  "sessionStarted" : "2015-12-xxx",
  "QuestionsSubmitted" : "2015-12-xxx"
  "answer" : {
    "0" : "answer a",
    "1" : "answer b"
    // etc //
  }
}
```

[This similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967233/sorting-aggregation-addtoset-result#answer-21967302), although useful, doesn't offer much of an idea in terms of doing this with grouping.