# mongodb sort on aggregate with group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meteor

I'm able to get a `distinct` group of `Documents` for a `Collection` by using `$group` and `aggregates`.

```
let uniqueFoos= Collection.rawCollection().aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: 0,
        foos: {
          $addToSet: '$foo'
        }
      }
    }
  ]).toArray().await();
```

This works great. But how can I sort the `foos` array in descending alphabetical order? I know how to do this standalone, but not how to insert it into the pipeline. I've tried inserting it before and after to no avail. Any ideas?

chaining a `.sort()` to the `.await()` can work, but I'd like to do this from the query itself. Thanks!

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967233/sorting-aggregation-addtoset-result

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following pipeline:

```
[
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$foo",
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "_id": -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: 0,
            foos: {
              $push: '$_id'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

But I think it will be much better if you just group and sort the data (without building an array within query). Try this pipeline:

```
[
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$profile.name",
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "_id": -1 }
    }
]
```

and then use the result array in your code.

NB: Also note, that MongoDB has [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method, but you will have to sort the results in js code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Orders.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } },
        "order": {
          "$sum": 1
      },
      
        total: {
          $sum: "$total_price"
        },
      
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { "_id": -1 }
  }
  ],
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I think it will be much better if you just group and sort the data (without building an array within query). Try this pipeline